# Detect if the recyclerview is updated

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a `RecyclerView` that contains a list of messages. I want to make a notification every time the user receive a message.
Because an update on the `RecyclerView` means that there is a new message.
I tried to make notifications when listening to the Firebase database messages node but it gives me a lot of notifications and make the app looks messy. Any suggestion?

Comment: Add relevant code snippet make your problem more clear.

Comment: The flux is not correct. RecyclerView show the data. Don't listen on View for data changed, listen on the data source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver) to observe your adapter's data.

it gives you a lot of options to to observe your adapter's data

- void onChanged()
- onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart, int itemCount, Object payload)
- onItemRangeChanged(int positionStart,int itemCount)
- onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount)
- onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition,int itemCount)
- onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount)

kotlin example:

```kotlin
mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver(){

 override fun onChanged() {
   // do work here
    super.onChanged()
 }

})
```

Comment: i think this is what i'm looking for! please can you provide me an example?

Comment: This still helps in 2023. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 0):

After updating your adapter instance, call your_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

More details [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html).